# Slow Compilation with Texmaker

Tags: unicode

When I open a texmaker file in my mac, it asks me: "It seems that this file can not be correctly decoded with the default encoding system (System). Use this encoding: UTF-8".
When I do this, my compilation becomes so slow and gets much of the CPU. It is also slow with choosing "System" instead of "UTF-8". Is there an encoding system among the suggested list that is better in terms of speed?

Comment: A slow compilation is usually pretty independent of the file encoding. It has much more impact if there are tons of unused packages and, e.g., many TikZ pictures.

Comment: Thanks! I have many figures using `include graphics`, is it going to be faster if I make the pictures pdf instead of jpg? Also is it going to be faster if I make the tables in separate files and use `input` or tables within the text are better in terms of speed?

Comment: Yes, PDF is usually faster. But inputting tables is not more effective.